# Get VSCode to use JSCS formatting rules

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jscs

Is there a way to integrate VSCode with JSCS? By that I mean: change the default indentation amount of spaces, make the format option (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) format the JavaScript code using `.jscsrc` rules and presets?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported, but we are working on a plugin story that would make this possible.